# angular 8 radio button not checked

Tags: angular, radio-button, angular8, angular-ngmodel

I have this html:

```
<div *ngFor="let option of systemEquipmentGroup">
              <h5>{{option.optionGroupName}}</h5>
              <div>
                <label style="display: block;" *ngFor="let opt of option.options; let i = index">
                  <input type="radio" (change)="onAct(opt)" style="position: inherit;" [name]="option.optionGroupName" [value]="opt.selected" />
                  {{opt.optionName}} {{opt.selected}}
                </label>
              </div>
          </div>
```

This is the output:

[image]

As you can see the values in the console are true/false.
I need the radio button to be checked if the value is true.

Anything I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `checked` property of input to achieve this. I have created a sample, you can check [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-lc313k?file=src/app/app.component.html)